# Measuring latency with switch and identifying flow path

Tags: switch, networking

I have two machines, A and B, connected via switch S1(master) and s2(slave). I want to measure latency and identify packet flow path from machine A to Switch,switch to machine B. If the link between s1 and A gets failed then packet will flow via s2 and A link.

I can't get A to Switch flowpath(A to s1 or A to s2)  using `traceroute` as Switch s1 and s2  is not a router. Is there any other network utility to flowpath and latency between A to B? I want to know whether the flow is via S1 or s2. Is there any tool.

Comment: Attach Computer C to the switch, from both A and B measure the latency to C.  Then check the difference.

Comment: my machine A is connected to switch S1(master) and s2(slave). If A to s1 gets down then A to s2 will be activated. Here i want to know the actual path and latency. Is there any tools will be there?

Comment: My point is that you shouldn't need any special tools, just use standard tools, and some math.  PS, I don't know anyway to directly measure switch latency.

Comment: @Zoredache I have edited my question.. Please give suggestions

Comment: Are the NICs and switches all on the same subnet? And what O/S are you using on the machines?

Comment: Yes.. All Nics and switches are in same subnets. I am using CentOS release 6.4